# Oracle11g installation on Solaris 10

Tags: database, solaris-10, database-installation

I am installing Oravcle 11G on Solaris 10 on a local sun machine. I have followed all the pre-req steps provided in oracle documentation but after all that when im trying to run the installer using oracle user. The installer checks pre-reqs and gives me the following error:

> > > > checking monitor: must be configured to display at 256 colors.
> > > >         couldnot execute autocheck for display colors using command /usr/openwin/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if dsiplay variables are set
> > > >
> > > > > to set Dispay variable i used the following command:  $DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 export DISPLAY

If i continue the installation by ignoring this error, it says:

> > Preparing to launch universal installer from /tmp/OraInstall2012-07-12_05-57-10PM. Please wait...$ Xlib: connection to "localhost:0.0" refused by server
> >     Xlib: Client is not authorised to connect to server.

Please not that im performing the installation locally on sun server.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the root session and log in back as oracle user, then issue `xclock` command, you should see the graphic clock appear. that means ok, so you can now run `./runinstaller` command in order to install oracle software.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

1) Log on to XWindows as root
2) Open a terminal
3) enter 'xhost +'
4) enter 'su - oracle'
5) enter 'export DISPLAY=:0.0'
6) runInstaller (or use whatever installer is required)

Answer (score 0):

open unix terminal
login as root

## xhost+

open another terminal
login as oracle user
$xclock

you should be able to see clock display. The you are good to run runInstaller.sh